# ChatX: A ruby library for SE Chat

Tags: library, chat, ruby

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Here's some sample usage:

```
cb = ChatBot.new(ENV['ChatXUsername'], ENV['ChatXPassword'])
cb.login

cb.gen_hooks do
  room 63296 do # Room ID of The Closet, a testing room for ChatX
    command("!!/alive") { say "I'm alive!" }
    command "!!/sum" do |*args|
      say "The sum is: #{args.map(&:to_i).sum}"
    end
    on "message" do |e|
      reply_to e, "You said: #{e.body}"
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more documentation and sample code in [the README](https://gitlab.com/izwick-schachter/ChatX/blob/master/README.md).

### About

I built this library because I saw no suitable alternative for ruby, my favorite language. I also thought it'd be fun to reverse engineer SE Chat, so I did. Now I've got a project. Yay!

#### License

This project is released under [the MIT License](https://gitlab.com/izwick-schachter/ChatX/blob/master/LICENSE.txt). Any contributions are welcome via pull requests. Feature requests can be made via issues or in chat.

#### Download

Although the library is [published on rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/chatx), the version there will frequently be outdated. To keep up to date please [install from GitHub](https://gitlab.com/izwick-schachter/ChatX). The master branch should never be broken, so `bundle update` regularly. This is easy if you're using the bundler gem, you can just add the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'chatx', git: 'https://gitlab.com/izwick-schachter/ChatX`, branch: 'master'
```

#### Platform

This library should work anywhere ruby will run. That means definitely macOS/Linux, and possibly windows.

### Contact

I made this library (with some help from @ArtOfCode and others). If you are getting started, I know that documentation is poor, so please ping me in chat. I can be found in either of the two testing rooms for this library, [Under the Bed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63561/under-the-bed) and [The Closet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63296/the-closet). Ping me whenever, I should respond within 48 hours.

In addition, if you have any feature requests, ping me in chat. I would be more than happy to try to add functions you need or to help you better use ChatX.

### Dependencies

- Developed with MRI Ruby 2.5.0
- WebSocket client written with [websocket-driver](https://rubygems.org/gems/websocket-driver) (with help from [permessage-deflate](https://rubygems.org/gems/permessage_deflate))
- HTML/XML parsing with [nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri)
- Parsing of chat message with help from [htmlentities](https://rubygems.org/gems/htmlentities)
- HTTP requests and persistence and cookies and awesomeness from [mechanize](https://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize)